# Blank page when viewing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

I cant seem to view my Web Application in Internet Explorer, the page just keeps on loading and nothing but a blank white page is shown. It doesnt matter if its an old Web Application or if I create a new one. It displays fine in Google Chrome.

Yesterday I upgraded from VS2010 to VS2012. I had no troubles viewing my Web Application when I used VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restoring Internet Explorer it started to work.